# COPY support with postgreSQL v12 triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers

We have this pair of trigger and function that we use on our psql database for the longest time. Basically, the trigger is called each time there is a new record to the main table, and each row is inserted to the monthly partition individually. Following is the trigger function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER partition_mic_teams_endpoint_trg1 
  BEFORE INSERT ON "mic_teams_endpoint" 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE 
PROCEDURE trg_partition_mic_teams_endpoint('month');
```

The function we have creates monthly partitions based on a timestamp field in each row.

I have two questions:

- List item Even if I try to COPY a bunch of rows from CSV to the main table, is this trigger/function going to insert each row individually? Is this efficient?
- If that is the case, is it possible to have support for COPYing data to partitions instead of INSERT.

Thanks,

Note: I am sorry if I did not provide enough information for an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a row level trigger will be called for each row separately, and that will make `COPY` quite a bit slower.

One thing you could try is a statement level `AFTER` trigger that uses a transition table, so that you can

```
INSERT INTO destination SELECT ... FROM transition_table;
```

That should be faster, but you should test it to be certain.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for details.